# Wayfinder - Pathfinder Application

Tags: mobile, path-finding

I want to create wayfinder/pathfinder mobile application. it will route visitors in our buildings. we have 20 buildings and each at least have 4 floor.

We want to develop our own wayfinder ex:http://www.wayfinderkiosk.com/

It should use Lat/Long coordinates to locate the people. and help to find its route.

So where should i start. Does any one have any idea for that. and it is going to be mobile.

I can develop app/site based on these platforms ( Mobile Web/Iphone/Adroid /Symbian/Windows )

But i need a start point. and i need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use lat/long inside of a building? Assuming these visitors are going to be using their own unmodified devices, you may have trouble with GPS. Unless you somehow get reliable GPS signal despite being under a four-story building, that's probably not going to work.

An RFID-tagged badge and sensors placed throughout the building seems more likely to work. Put a unique QR-code on each badge that directs the phone's browser to a tracking page for that specific badge.

edit: and now that I re-read your question and see that multiple buildings are involved, the GPS bit could certainly work for routing them from one building to another.

Comment: i am going to use wifi's for that. i know all wifi location so i can get actual position. but for starters i am assuming that i will get correct position.

Comment: Hmm. Other than that, I would look into the Spatialite database (an extension of SQLite3) for representing regions on your map. It also has a module for route finding, though I believe you need to specify waypoints. Not sure how well it would work for the indoor parts. PostGIS probably has something similar/better, if you already have a Postgres database.